# MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy on HPC hanging when OOM happens

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, slurm

I'm running neural net with custom dataset on multiple nodes (4 nodes with 8 gpu each), however, some gpu within a node is out of memory and `model.fit` raised **ResourceExhaustedError** but do not terminate for about one day. I also try to run on 1 node with 4 gpu. When oom happens, `model.fit` terminate in 5 minute as expected.

The question is, running with TensorFlow MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy on more nodes when OOM happens on some gpu will hang without termination?

Info:

- Managing tools on HPC: Slurm
- Deep learning package: TensorFlow 2.3

Error log: [link](https://taoinfocomtw-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/patrick_lee_terminating_ai/EZURFBMVFshAj-EfNRKxfyUBwhSdxLzSHAzBP1q7y1o0YA?e=bcv81h)

Any help is appreciated!